# Store and retrieve $_GET statement from MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, get

I have a stored url in a MySQL database. (`http://example.com/page.php?ex='$_GET[ex]'`) When I retrieve it to create a dynamic link it gives me `http://example.com/page.php?ex=%27.$_GET[ex].%27` and of course won't work.

I can't seem to be able to get (sorry had to use it!) the `$_GET` variable.

To be exact the cell contains...

```
Submit Risk Assessment<button><a href="risksearch.php?ex='.$_GET[ex].'">Create / Edit</a></button>
```

Comment: Don't store literal PHP source code in the database! Store text with placeholders, which you then interpolate. The simplest example is [`sprintf`](http://php.net/sprintf).

Comment: hmmm...sprintf not quite what I was after...I think that would be useful f the  link was stored on its own and retrieved. It was hard to explain... I basically have a todo list, but only a few of the items will have links to other forms. I was trying to store this as text and links in the database. Works fine without the $_GET variable. Is it something that can be done.

Comment: I may have to add another field in the DB and call it separately using sprintf. Shame as there are only 3 out of 70 tasks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not really answering the question, but my solution was to create a separate field in the database for the url only. I then used deceze's suggestion of sprintf and it works perfectly.

```
    if(!empty($row[buttonlink])){
        $ex = $_GET[ex];
        $rawlink = $row[buttonlink];

        $format = '<button><a href="%s?ex=%s">Create / Edit</a></button>';
        $buttonlink = sprintf($format, $rawlink, $ex);
}
```

Only had a small number of buttons to do and they could all be labelled 'Create / Edit'. I could add another field to have the label called into the sprintf too.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the string have been encoded by urlencode

You should decode the url encoded string

```
$a = urldecode('http://example.com/page.php?ex=%27.$_GET[ex].%27');
echo $a;
// print the url
```

Comment: Thanks Philippe T. I have other text in the same field an probably (for design reasons) split it into its own field - which I have done and used deceze's suggestion of sprint.